# Start remote VM using vmrun

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools, vmrun

Okay, I know this looks silly but I already spent like 2 days on this :-/

I have a host machine where I am running VMWare Workstation(9.0.3) and 1 VM (Ubuntu 12.04). I have vmrun utility installed on both Host and Guest machines.

The questions is, from the Guest machine, how do I get list of all running VMs on the host machine?

I tried with following commands on guest but all returned 0 (though this guest is running on the host!):
- vmrun -T ws -h  list
- vmrun -T ws -h  -u  -p  list
- vmrun -T ws -h :8333/sdk -u  -p  list

In ifconfig command output, I see 3 addresses for these interfaces: eth0, vmnet1 and vmnet8. I tried with all of them but no luck!

My motto at the end of the day is to be able to list and admin VMs on remote hosts from Java code!

Thanks a lot in advance!